# If |A×B|=3 , and each of And and B is parallel to the plane YZ , Find A×B A×B is Cross product of vectors

Tags: solid-geometry

If $|A×B|=3$ , and each of $A$ And and $B$ is parallel  to the plane $YZ$ , Find $A×B$

$A×B$  is Cross product of vectors

Comment: $A\times B$ is a vector perpendicular to both $A$ and $B$. Since $|A\times B|=3\neq0$ the vectors $A$ and $B$ are not parallel to each other. Therefore $A\times B$ is perpendicular to the plane $YZ$, i.e. it belongs to the $X$ axis. Therefore $A\times B$ is either $(3,0,0)$ or $(-3,0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A\times B$ is parallel to $X$ axis and as its module is $3$ it can be

$(3,0,0)$ or $(-3,0,0)$